# How to query xml data in a table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with columns ID and XML. The column XML contains data in XML but is not of xml type, actually it's varchar. I need to get values from ID column and nazwa_saduPOZEW from xml column.
Here's the xml structure:

```
<RootElement>
<DocumentContent>
<Root>
<Pelnomoc_miasto type="SingleValue">xxx</Pelnomoc_miasto>
<data_biezaca type="SingleValue">xxx</data_biezaca>
<nazwa_powoda type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_powoda>
<powod_adres_ulica type="SingleValue">xxx</powod_adres_ulica>
<powod_adres_miasto type="SingleValue">xxx</powod_adres_miasto>
<TytulPelnomocnika type="SingleValue">xxx</TytulPelnomocnika>
<imie_nazwisko_pelnomocnikaPOZEW
type="SingleValue">xxx</imie_nazwisko_pelnomocnikaPOZEW>
<nazwa_saduPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_saduPOZEW>
<nazwa_rozszerzenona_saduPOZEW
type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_rozszerzenona_saduPOZEW> 
<sad_adresPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</sad_adresPOZEW>
<sad_kod_miastoPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</sad_kod_miastoPOZEW>
<sygnatura_sadowa type="SingleValue">xxx</sygnatura_sadowa>
<data_cesji type="SingleValue">xxx</data_cesji>
<wierzytelnosc_numer type="SingleValue">xxx</wierzytelnosc_numer>
<wierzytelnosc_data type="SingleValue">xxx</wierzytelnosc_data>
</Root>
</DocumentContent>
<ToDo>GenerateAndSaveDocument</ToDo>
<OutBoxFolder>xxx</OutBoxFolder>
<czyPodglad>0</czyPodglad>
<TemplatePath>xxx</TemplatePath>
<OutputPath>xxx</OutputPath>
<isPDF>false</isPDF>
<makeWatermark>false</makeWatermark>
</RootElement>
```

I've already tried to query this table and I've managed so far to get a value nazwa_saduPOZEW but only for one row and without ID column (I badly need this column to join to another table).

Here's my code:

```
declare @xmldata XML

select @xmldata=pismo_tagi
from debtmanager_tagi_pism..tagi_pism
where ak_id=4289062

select 
Tabliczka.element.value('nazwa_saduPOZEW[1]','varchar(max)') as 
nazwa_sadu

from @xmldata.nodes ('/RootElement/DocumentContent/Root') as   
Tabliczka(element)
```

My desire output is ID column and xml column as nazwa_saduPOZEW for all rows in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select ak_id,
xmldata.value('/RootElement[1]/DocumentContent[1]/Root[1]/nazwa_saduPOZEW[1]', 'varchar(max)') as nazwa_sadu
     from (select ak_id, cast(pismo_tagi as XML) as xmldata  from dbo.tagi_pism) as t
```

it works fine on this data sample:

```
create table tagi_pism (ak_id int, pismo_tagi varchar (max))
go
insert tagi_pism
select 4289062, '<RootElement>
<DocumentContent>
<Root>
<Pelnomoc_miasto type="SingleValue">xxx</Pelnomoc_miasto>
<data_biezaca type="SingleValue">xxx</data_biezaca>
<nazwa_powoda type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_powoda>
<powod_adres_ulica type="SingleValue">xxx</powod_adres_ulica>
<powod_adres_miasto type="SingleValue">xxx</powod_adres_miasto>
<TytulPelnomocnika type="SingleValue">xxx</TytulPelnomocnika>
<imie_nazwisko_pelnomocnikaPOZEW
type="SingleValue">xxx</imie_nazwisko_pelnomocnikaPOZEW>
<nazwa_saduPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_saduPOZEW>
<nazwa_rozszerzenona_saduPOZEW
type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_rozszerzenona_saduPOZEW> 
<sad_adresPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</sad_adresPOZEW>
<sad_kod_miastoPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</sad_kod_miastoPOZEW>
<sygnatura_sadowa type="SingleValue">xxx</sygnatura_sadowa>
<data_cesji type="SingleValue">xxx</data_cesji>
<wierzytelnosc_numer type="SingleValue">xxx</wierzytelnosc_numer>
<wierzytelnosc_data type="SingleValue">xxx</wierzytelnosc_data>
</Root>
</DocumentContent>
<ToDo>GenerateAndSaveDocument</ToDo>
<OutBoxFolder>xxx</OutBoxFolder>
<czyPodglad>0</czyPodglad>
<TemplatePath>xxx</TemplatePath>
<OutputPath>xxx</OutputPath>
<isPDF>false</isPDF>
<makeWatermark>false</makeWatermark>
</RootElement>'
union select 4289063, '<RootElement>
<DocumentContent>
<Root>
<Pelnomoc_miasto type="SingleValue">xxx</Pelnomoc_miasto>
<data_biezaca type="SingleValue">xxx</data_biezaca>
<nazwa_powoda type="SingleValue">xxx</nazwa_powoda>
<powod_adres_ulica type="SingleValue">xxx</powod_adres_ulica>
<powod_adres_miasto type="SingleValue">xxx</powod_adres_miasto>
<TytulPelnomocnika type="SingleValue">xxx</TytulPelnomocnika>
<imie_nazwisko_pelnomocnikaPOZEW
type="SingleValue">xxx</imie_nazwisko_pelnomocnikaPOZEW>
<nazwa_saduPOZEW type="SingleValue">yyy</nazwa_saduPOZEW>
<nazwa_rozszerzenona_saduPOZEW
type="SingleValue">yyy</nazwa_rozszerzenona_saduPOZEW> 
<sad_adresPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</sad_adresPOZEW>
<sad_kod_miastoPOZEW type="SingleValue">xxx</sad_kod_miastoPOZEW>
<sygnatura_sadowa type="SingleValue">xxx</sygnatura_sadowa>
<data_cesji type="SingleValue">xxx</data_cesji>
<wierzytelnosc_numer type="SingleValue">xxx</wierzytelnosc_numer>
<wierzytelnosc_data type="SingleValue">xxx</wierzytelnosc_data>
</Root>
</DocumentContent>
<ToDo>GenerateAndSaveDocument</ToDo>
<OutBoxFolder>xxx</OutBoxFolder>
<czyPodglad>0</czyPodglad>
<TemplatePath>xxx</TemplatePath>
<OutputPath>xxx</OutputPath>
<isPDF>false</isPDF>
<makeWatermark>false</makeWatermark>
</RootElement>'
```

the result is:

```
ak_id   nazwa_sadu
4289062 xxx
4289063 yyy
```